# implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' unable syncing

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'


    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
}

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

module app is not able to sync due to the addition of this tag `"firebase message"` and error under this line can be seen from the code written above in line.

Comment: did you mean project is not sync after added appcompat dependency?

Comment: user "older version" of same gradle as you're not using "Android X". or migrate while project to "Android X".

Comment: No, not due to appcompat dependency.on importing the file of cloud messages into this build.gradle file.Error arrises under the "appcompat" line and let it not able to sync

Comment: can I change the version of gradle in the mid of the project without changing the whole project